# Does plutus-pab support parallel requests?

Tags: plutus, plutus-pab

1. Does plutus-pab support parallel requests to the same smart contract instance?
2. Does plutus-pab support parallel requests to different smart contract instances?

By parallel requests I mean calling instance endpoints.